# stl::multimap - how do i get groups of data?

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

Multimap essentially has groups of data sorted by the key. I want a method by which I could access these individual groups and get their aggregate values.
For example, in a `std::multimap< string, int >` I store

```
{"Group1", 1}, 
{"Group1", 2}, 
{"Group1", 3}, 

{"Group2", 10}, 
{"Group2", 11}, 
{"Group2", 12}
```

Having stored these values, I should be able to iterate this multimap and get the aggregate values of each "group". Problem is there aren't any functions defined in STL to access MultiMaps in such a way. I could use `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` to manually iterate the multimap and total the group's contents, but I am hoping there could be better ways already defined in STL ? Can anyone propose a solution as to how I could get the aggregate values for a group in the above example.

Comment: Very elegant and lambda method described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37680747/5516759

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
pair<Iter, Iter> range = my_multimap.equal_range("Group1");
int total = accumulate(range.first, range.second, 0);
```

Is one way.

**Edit:**

If you don't know the group you are looking for, and are just going through each group, getting the next group's range can be done like so:

```
template <typename Pair>
struct Less : public std::binary_function<Pair, Pair, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const Pair &x, const Pair &y) const
    {
        return x.first < y.first;
    }
};

Iter first = mmap.begin();
Iter last = adjacent_find(first, mmap.end(), Less<MultimapType::value_type>());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x.first == y.first;`? Why have you used `operator<`? According to the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/) of `adjacent_find`, the predicate parameter should return the result of the comparison with true (non-zero) meaning that they are to be considered equal, and false (zero) for not-equal. Why are you returning true for non-equal result?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a mistake. `adjacent_find` expects an "equal" predicate. Also, I'm sure that there is `std::equal_to<T>` ready to use.

Comment: @leemes I believe your edit changes the behavior to incorrect one. "Less than" operator was supposed to find last element before the key is changed (which could be `advance`d by 1 to the first element with new key), while with equality operator it will just return iterator to the same (`first`) element

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit to the original @Greg's version

Answer (score 25):

```
// samekey.cpp -- Process groups with identical keys in a multimap

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef multimap<string, int> StringToIntMap;
typedef StringToIntMap::iterator mapIter;

int main ()
{
    StringToIntMap mymap;

    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group2", 11));
    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group1",  3));
    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group2", 10));
    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group1",  1));
    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group2", 12));
    mymap.insert(make_pair("Group1",  2));

    cout << "mymap contains:" << endl;

    mapIter m_it, s_it;

    for (m_it = mymap.begin();  m_it != mymap.end();  m_it = s_it)
    {
        string theKey = (*m_it).first;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "  key = '" << theKey << "'" << endl;

        pair<mapIter, mapIter> keyRange = mymap.equal_range(theKey);

        // Iterate over all map elements with key == theKey

        for (s_it = keyRange.first;  s_it != keyRange.second;  ++s_it)
        {
           cout << "    value = " << (*s_it).second << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}   //  end main

// end samekey.cpp
```

Comment: @RogerHouse is there any way to get count before we start iterating from first to last entry against same key.

Answer (score 11):

If you already know the keys, you can use `multimap::equal_range` to get the iterators to the beginning and end of the group; use any standard algorithm to get the desired results from the range.  If you don't know the keys, you can start at `begin()` and iterate through them yourself, comparing keys to find the start of each new group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternate container that can contain the aggregate sums of each group. To do this you might do something like:

```
template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
struct group_add {
  typedef map<KeyType, ValueType> map_type;
  map_type & aggregates;
  explicit group_add(map_type & aggregates_)
    : aggregates(aggregates_) { };
  void operator() (map_type::value_type const & element) {
    aggregates[element.first] += element.second;
  };
};

template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
group_add<KeyType, ValueType>
make_group_adder(map<KeyType, ValueType> & map_) {
  return group_add<KeyType, ValueType>(map_);
};

// ...
multimap<string, int> members;
// populate members
map<string, int> group_aggregates;
for_each(members.begin(), members.end(),
  make_group_adder(group_aggregates));
// group_aggregates now has the sums per group
```

Of course, if you have Lambda's (in C++0x) it could be simpler:

```
multimap<string, int> members;
map<string, int> group_aggregates;
for_each(members.begin(), members.end(),
  [&group_aggregates](multimap<string, int>::value_type const & element) {
    group_aggregates[element.first] += element.second;
  }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
equal_range
```

Syntax:

```
#include <map>
pair<iterator, iterator> equal_range( const key_type& key );
```

The function `equal_range()` returns two iterators - one to the first element that contains key, another to a point just after the last element that contains key.

Answer (score -1):

Not a multimap answer, but you can do things like the following if you so choose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main() {
    typedef map<string, vector<int> > collection;
    collection m;
    m["Group 1"] = list_of(1)(2)(3);
    m["Group 2"] = list_of(10)(11)(12);
    collection::iterator g2 = m.find("Group 2");
    if (g2 != m.end()) {
        BOOST_FOREACH(int& i, g2->second) {
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```