# How to iterate/count for a multimap<string,string>

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, multimap

My class is like this:

```
class Outgoing
{
    multimap<string,string> outgoing;

    public:
    void makeConnection(string key, string value)
    {
        outgoing.insert(pair<string,string>(key,value));
    }

    void iterate()
    {
        multimap<string, string>::iterator it;
        multimap<string, string>::iterator it2;
        pair<multimap<string,string>::iterator,multimap<string,string>::iterator> ret;
        for (it = outgoing.begin();it != outgoing.end();++it)
        {
            ret = outgoing.equal_range((*it));  ??????
            for (it2=ret.first; it2!=ret.second; ++it2)
            {
                ???????

             }
        }
    }
};
```

background:

I want to represent a graph which can have many nodes. The key won't repeat but can have multiple values.

```
str1  ----> val1
str1  ----> val2
str2 -----> val3
```

I want to know how can I get number of values for a particular key? for e.g. in the above question , for str1 it will be 2?

As you can see , I tried to do something after some digging around but in vain.

What is wrong with my code?

thanks

EDIT ::: after templatetypedef's comment, I edited the code to:

```
for (it = outgoing.begin();it != outgoing.end();++it)
{
    cout<< (*it).first << " "<<  outgoing.count((*it).first); 

}
```

I can get the count, but the key("str1") comes twice. So the answer I see is 2 2 1.

I would appreciate it very much, if somebody teaches me how to iterate in such a way I get only one key. BTW, thanks, templatetypedef

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792682/skip-same-multimap-values-when-iterating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there an iterator across unique keys in a std::multimap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371236/is-there-an-iterator-across-unique-keys-in-a-stdmultimap)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `count` function for this, which returns the number of entries in the `multimap` with the the given key.  In your example, writing

```
outgoing.count("str1")
```

would produce the value 2.

In C++, there is no way to iterate over just the unique keys in a `multimap`.  If you want to iterate over just those keys, there are two options you might want to consider:

1. You could change from using a `multimap< string, string >` to `map<string, vector<string> >`.  That way, each key is unique, and you can easily determine how many values are associated with each key by just looking at the number of elements in the corresponding `vector`.
2. You could have a top-level loop to iterate over all keys, then have an inner loop to skip duplicate keys.

As an example of option 2, you might try something like this:

```
for (multimap<string, string>::iterator itr = myMap.begin(); itr != myMap.end(); ) {
    /* ... process *itr ... */

    /* Now, go skip to the first entry with a new key. */
    multimap<string, string>::iterator curr = itr;
    while (itr != myMap.end() && itr->first == curr->first)
        ++itr;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quick question, why'd you rollback an edit that removed "[fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/2246344)"?

Comment: @Sam I have a habit of concluding all my answers with "Hope this helps!", so I figured I'd go for consistency. :-)

Comment: maybe you should use upper_bound() inside the for loop declaration; instead of looping yourself

Answer (score 8):

The function equal_range provides a pair of iterators, with the first and last elements of the map thar share a certain key.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/

```
// multimap::equal_range
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::multimap<char,int> mymm;

  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('a',10));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',20));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',30));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',40));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',50));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',60));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('d',60));

  std::cout << "mymm contains:\n";
  for (char ch='a'; ch<='d'; ch++)
  {
    std::pair <std::multimap<char,int>::iterator, std::multimap<char,int>::iterator> ret;
    ret = mymm.equal_range(ch);
    std::cout << ch << " =>";
    for (std::multimap<char,int>::iterator it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it)
      std::cout << ' ' << it->second;
    std::cout << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```