# is there an iterator across unique keys in a std::multimap?

Tags: c++, multimap

Is there a simple or standard way to have a multimap iterator which iterate across unique keys in a multimap?

i.e. for a set that looks like: `{1, "a"}, {1, "lemon"}, {2, "peacock"}, {3, "angel"}`
an iterator which would start at `{1, "a"}` then incrementing would point to `{2, "peacock"}` and then incrementing again would point to `{3, "angel"}`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `upper_bound` to increment the iterator position instead of `++`:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  multimap<int,string> mm;
  mm.insert(make_pair(1, "a"));
  mm.insert(make_pair(1, "lemon"));
  mm.insert(make_pair(2, "peacock"));
  mm.insert(make_pair(3, "angel"));

  for( auto it = mm.begin(), end = mm.end();
       it != end;
       it = mm.upper_bound(it->first)
  )
    cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This [results in](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/968e4717d4375ea6):

```
1 a
2 peacock
3 angel
```

Comment: But what out for the O(n log n) complexity this entailed, instead of the normal O(n) traversal, as mentioned in @user3701170's answer.

Comment: @ddevienne sadly, nowadays everyone chooses elegance over performance.

Comment: performance may depend on data layout. Given N as number of keys and M as number of entries, complexity of trivial loop would be O(M), and complexity of binary search loop O(N log M). It is easy to prove the latter is smaller if N << M.

Answer (score 33):

Using `upper_bound` would result in an easy-to-read loop but each call will perform a binary tree search, resulting in an *O(n log n)* instead of *O(n)* traversal. If the difference in efficiency matters, you can structure your traversal like this:

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, int> MapType;
MapType container;
for (MapType::iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ) {
  std::string key = it->first;

  doSomething(key);

  // Advance to next non-duplicate entry.
  do {
    ++it;
  } while (it != container.end() && key == it->first);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. A `while(true)` + `goto` version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41523639/895245

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the selected answer, repeated use of `multimap::upper_bound` leads to an O(n log n) traversal of the map.  Using the external `upper_bound` function gives you O(n).  However, you need to ensure you only compare the key of the map:

```
std::multimap<int, std::string> myMap = ... ;
const auto compareFirst = [](const std::pair<const int, std::string>& lhs, const std::pair<const int, std::string>& rhs) {
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
};

for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it = std::upper_bound(it, myMap.end(), *it, compareFirst)) {
    // Do stuff...

}
```

The underlying approach is essentially the same as user3701170's solution - i.e linear search - but we put the increment step in the `for` statement proper, not the loop's body.  Aside from putting the increment where it "usually" lives, this also means any `continue` statements in the loop will behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Runnable example**

This is a slight improvement over https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212648/895245 with a runnable unit test:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // For testing.
    auto m = std::multimap<int, int>{
        {1, 2},
        {1, 3},
        {2, 4}
    };
    std::vector<int> out;

    // The algorithm.
    auto it = m.begin();
    auto end = m.end();
    while (it != end) {
        auto key = it->first;

        // Do what you want to do with the keys.
        out.push_back(key);

        do {
            if (++it == end)
                break;
        } while (it->first == key);
    }

    // Assert it worked.
    assert(out == std::vector<int>({1, 2}));
}
```

Comment: I encourage everybody to avoid the use of goto. And here it is avoided by replacing "goto end;" -> "break;" and "while (true)" -> "while (it != end)"

Comment: @bebbo thanks for the edit, but I think the code wouldn't work because of the lack of update to `key`. Please make sure you compile and run it ;-)

Comment: @bebbo I also have to sleep :-) I wish there was a way to not have 2 `it == end` comparisons, even if that requires `goto`.

Comment: You need at least a check for an empty map. So there are always 2 comparisons in the code.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to pass over all unique keys quickly then you can use std::map instead;

```
typedef std::map< KeyType, std::list< ValueType > > MapKeyToMultiValue;
```

Insertion would be more difficult, However you can iterate over all keys without having to bother with duplicate entries. Insertion would look as follows:

```
void insert_m(MapKeyToMultiValue &map, const KeyType key, const ValueType value )
{
  auto it = map.find( key );
  if (it == map.end())
  {
     std::list<ValueType> empty;
     std::pair< MapKeyToMultiValue::iterator, bool > ret =
        map.insert( MapKeyToMultiValue::value_type( key, empty ) );
     it = ret.first;
  }

  it->second.push_back( value );
}
```

or you can make that very templated:

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType, 
     typename MapType = std::map< KeyType, std::list< ValueType > > >
void insert_multi( MapType &map, const KeyType key, const ValueType value )
{

  auto it = map.find( key );
  if (it == map.end())
  {
     std::list<ValueType> empty;
     std::pair< typename MapType::iterator, bool > ret =
        map.insert( typename MapType::value_type( key, empty ) );
     it = ret.first;
  }

  it->second.push_back( value );
}
```

The full test program looks as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef std::string KeyType;  
typedef int ValueType;

typedef std::map< KeyType, std::list< ValueType > >  MapKeyToMultiValue;

void insert_m(MapKeyToMultiValue &map, const KeyType key, const ValueType value )
{
  auto it = map.find( key );
  if (it == map.end())
  {
     std::list<ValueType> empty;
     std::pair< MapKeyToMultiValue::iterator, bool > ret =
        map.insert( MapKeyToMultiValue::value_type( key, empty ) );
     it = ret.first;
  }

  it->second.push_back( value );
}


template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType, 
   typename MapType = std::map< KeyType, std::list< ValueType > > >
void insert_multi( MapType &map, const KeyType key, const ValueType value )
{

  auto it = map.find( key );
  if (it == map.end())
  {
     std::list<ValueType> empty;
     std::pair< typename MapType::iterator, bool > ret =
        map.insert( typename MapType::value_type( key, empty ) );
     it = ret.first;
  }

  it->second.push_back( value );
}


int main()
{
    MapKeyToMultiValue map;


    insert_m(map, std::string("aaa"), 1 );
    insert_m(map, std::string("aaa"), 2 );
    insert_m(map, std::string("bb"), 3 );
    insert_m(map, std::string("cc"), 4 );


    insert_multi(map, std::string("ddd"), 1 );
    insert_multi(map, std::string("ddd"), 2 );
    insert_multi(map, std::string("ee"), 3 );
    insert_multi(map, std::string("ff"), 4 );


    for(auto i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ++i)
    {
      printf("%s\n", i->first.c_str() );
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is way over-complicated.  Insert for `std::map<int, std::list<int> > map;` is just `map[1].push_back(2);` .  If the `operator[]` lookup doesn't find anything, the list is default constructed, which is very convenient here.

Answer (score 0):

Try `equal_range`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range

That must be an exact match.

Comment: `equal_range` takes a multimap key in entry... so it's not good if the need is to retrieve keys...