# How can I get all the unique keys in a multimap

Tags: c++, stl, std, multimap

I have a multimap and I want get all the unique keys in it to be stored in a vector.

```
  multimap<char,int> mymm;
  multimap<char,int>::iterator it;
  char c;

  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('x',50));
  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('y',100));
  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('y',150));
  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('y',200));
  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('z',250));
  mymm.insert(pair<char,int>('z',300));
```

How can I do this? there is way to count number of elements with a key but none to count number of unique keys in a multimap.

**Added:** By unique I mean all the keys in multimap once - they can be repeated or occur once in multimap.

So unique keys here are - **x**, **y** and **z**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there an iterator across unique keys in a std::multimap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371236/is-there-an-iterator-across-unique-keys-in-a-stdmultimap)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I tried this and it worked

```
for(  multimap<char,int>::iterator it = mymm.begin(), end = mymm.end(); it != end; it = mymm.upper_bound(it->first))
  {
      cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << endl;
  }
```

Comment: It will print all the elements

Comment: I want all the keys just once - does not matter if the keys were repeated.

Comment: @AJ see the `upper_bound` part, this should print every key only once

Comment: It involves searching in the whole map on every iteration.

Comment: @Roman: no it does not.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound

Comment: @Bklyn: upper_bound searches in the whole map, just as I said. Better algorithm for OP problem could search next key only in keys greater than previously found key, but there is no such function in c++ multimap.

Comment: I got a deprecation warning on `upper_bound` with the hint to use `equal_range().second`. After changing to that, everything worked fine.

Comment: i also used `equal_range().second`  instead of `upper_bound()` and got improved efficiency

Answer (score 18):

Since the entries of a `std::multimap<>` are implicitly sorted and come out in sorted order when iterating through them, you can use the `std::unique_copy` algorithm for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  /* ...Your existing code... */

  /* Create vector of deduplicated entries: */
  vector<pair<char,int>> keys_dedup;
  unique_copy(begin(mymm),
              end(mymm),
              back_inserter(keys_dedup),
              [](const pair<char,int> &entry1,
                 const pair<char,int> &entry2) {
                   return (entry1.first == entry2.first);
               }
             );

  /* Print unique keys, just to confirm. */
  for (const auto &entry : keys_dedup)
    cout << entry.first << '\n';

  cout.flush();
  return 0;
}
```

**The extra work added by this is linear in the number of entries of the multimap, whereas using a `std::set` or Jeeva's approach for deduplication both add O(n log n) computational steps.**

*Remark:* The lambda expression I use assumes C++11. It is possible to rewrite this for C++03.

Comment: Why doesn't the std::multimap already have within it a simple vector/list/set/map of all the unique keys. This seems like it would be useful and not that much overhead. Does this feature not exists because people wouldn't use this functionality that much or rather because the overhead is more than what i am guessing it would be? I would not think space would be a requirement (Right?).

Comment: @Fractal I'm not sure I understand your proposal completely. An extra data structure for this would take O(n) extra space, no? One thing that would be nice, though, is an interface (e.g. a special iterator) that would return the unique keys one by one.

Comment: Yes, true ... it would be O(n) extra space. I don't think of space as actually being an issue but maybe in my work I don't deal with large enough groups of data to understand how that would be a strain/issue.  Yes, a special iterator would be ideal.

Comment: But you are not storing only the keys as required in the question... what are you storing exactly?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is more efficient than @jeeva's approach. for my data-set , my benchmark says this took ~1-2 seconds while Jeeva's approach took .3 seconds. I had about 4.7million values, 3642 of which were unique

Comment: @road_to_quantdom Thanks for testing it!

Comment: i also used `equal_range().second` instead of `upper_bound` but their performance was somewhat similar

Answer (score 9):

Iterate through all elements of `mymm`, and store `it->first` in a `set<char>`.

Comment: -1. it will not give unique keys. It will give all keys. For example if there are two keys 'a' you will have the key 'a' in your set, but it's not unique

Comment: @Andrew `set` will only keep unique elements. It _will_ give unique keys.

Comment: +1 as I just wrote using a set as a comment in the other answer! ;)

Comment: @Andrew on edit: unique means one of each kind. If there are two 'a' keys in multimap, then unique set must contain one 'a'

Comment: @Fiktik: generally unique means that there is one object of a kind. If there are two 'a' keys in a multimap then the key is not unique.

Comment: @Andrew please take a look at `std::unique`. When talking about collections, term 'unique' is pretty precisely defined I think.

Comment: I think what Andrew means is "keys that occur only once in the multimap in the first place", and what Donotalo and Fiktik mean are "a deduplicated list of all keys". Both are valid interpretations of the English word "unique" I believe.

Comment: I agree that both interpretations are possible. Sorry, can't remove -1 until answer is edited

Comment: The rationale behind your downvote is pedantic and unhelpful. The OP is clearly looking for the deduped list of keys, which `set` provides. It may not be the best possible way to skin this particular cat, but it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

easiest way would be to put the keys of multimap in an unordered_set

```
unordered_multimap<string, string> m;

//insert data in multimap

unordered_set<string> s;         //set to store the unique keys

for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++){
    if(s.find(it->first) == s.end()){
        s.insert(it->first);
        auto its = m.equal_range(it->first);
        for(auto itr=its.first;itr!=its.second;itr++){
            cout<<itr->second<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this in case by `unique` you mean the key that is contained in the `multimap` only once:

1) construct a sorted `list` of all keys in your map

2) iterate over the list and find unique keys. It's simple since all duplicates will be near each other in a sorted container

If you want just all keys - use `std::set` as Donotalo suggested

Comment: why use a sorted list and not just a set? the set will already prove uniqueness.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: because if there are two keys 'a' in the multimap the key 'a' will be in the set, but it's not unique

Comment: a is a key, even if it is used multiple times, it is still a key that has to be stored. At least I understand the question as not wanting a list of keys that are not used multiple times, but a list of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to insert them into a vector and then just use, `std::sort` and `std::unique`

```
template<typename Container> static
std::vector<typename Container::key_type> unique_keys(Container A)
{

    using ValueType = typename Container::key_type;

    std::vector<ValueType> v;

    for(auto ele : A)
    {
        v.push_back(ele.first);
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.resize(distance(v.begin(),it));

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in O(N) where N is the size of your map; your keys do not need to have an order operator:

```
template<typename Container>
std::vector<typename Container::key_type> UniqueKeys (const Container &A)
{
std::vector<typename Container::key_type> v;
auto prevIter = A.begin ();

for (auto iter = A.begin (); iter != A.end(); ++iter)
    {
    if (prevIter->first == iter->first)
        continue;

    v.push_back (prevIter->first);
    prevIter = iter;
    }

if (prevIter != A.end ())
    v.push_back (prevIter->first);

return v;
}
```