# how to loop multimap only to get first key-value pairs for every key?

Tags: c++, iteration, multimap

For example if I have such mmap:

```
alice -> 30
bob -> 23
josh -> 20
josh -> 30
andy -> 40
andy -> 40
```

to get only this pairs:

```
alice -> 30
bob -> 23
josh -> 20
andy -> 40
```

Comment: Probable dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554932/how-can-i-get-all-the-unique-keys-in-a-multimap

Comment: Do you need just one (basically randomly chosen) pair for every key, or actually the first (by what metric)?

Comment: @Grizzly: well, what is easier, I don't really need the value on the spot. I could later fetch the value that I want.

Comment: @Shafik that doesn't look like a duplicate to me. This question wants to locate the "first" (whatever that means) *value* for each unique key, and the one you've linked to wants to identify the unique keys themselves (without caring about the values, or which one is "first").

Comment: @rsk82 So you actually just need all the unique keys?

Comment: @DrewDormann: actually yes, from what it works (since I din't know that asking this question) I can get whatever value I want, first, last middle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This oughta do it as clean, and effective, as possible:

```
for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it = m.upper_bound(it->first)) {
  std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That is not really more than what is already in the link I put in the comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554932/how-can-i-get-all-the-unique-keys-in-a-multimap

Comment: M M: uhm what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short answer, but not the most efficient

```
multimap<string, int> mm;
// Add stuff to multimap

// Map with only the first items from multimap
map<string,int> m;

for(auto iter = mm.rbegin(); iter != mm.rend(); ++iter){
   m[iter->first] = iter->second;
}
```

This works because we start from the end. Thus any duplicate keys in multimap will overwrite the previous key in map. Since we start from the end, we should have the first key