# How to iterate through a multimap and print values grouped by key?

Tags: c++, count, key, multimap

I have `std::multimap<string, MyObject*> dataMap;` where the keys are `MyObject.name` and all MyObjects are stored in a `std::vector<MyObject>`.

After filling the map I need to print the contents of `dataMap` grouped by the same key, where I first need number of same keys with the help of `dataMap.count(MyObject.name)` and then all the values with this key.

I was thinking of using two `for loops` where the first loop iterates through "key group names" and counts all the keys that belong in this group, and the other `for loop` iterates through all the keys in certain group and prints the `MyObject.information`

```
for(//iterate through group key names){
   //print number of key occurences
   for(//iterate through a certain group{
      //print MyObject.information for all the keys in a group
   }

}
```

The problem is, i don't really know how would implement this or rather how would I use iterators to my will. Any ideas?

EDIT: From the provided links i created this

```
 for(std::multimap<string, MyObject*>::const_iterator itUnq = dataMap.cbegin();
     itUnq != dataMap.cend(); itUnq = dataMap.upper_bound(itUnq->first)){

        std::cout << dataMap.count(itUnq->second->name)
                  << std::endl;

        std::pair <std::multimap<string, MyObject*>::const_iterator, 
                   std::multimap<string, MyObject*>::const_iterator> groupRange;
        groupRange = dataMap.equal_range(itUnq->second->code);

        //iterate through keys inside the group
        for(std::multimap<string, MyObject*>::const_iterator itGroup = groupRange.first;
            itGroup != groupRange.second; ++itGroup){

            std::cout << itGroup->second->information

        }
```

Comments?

Comment: What does "all MyObjects are stored in a std::vector<MyObject>" mean? You also said the `dataMap` keys were `*MyObject` 0 u.e. just a pointer to MyObject... and a potential memory leak, right?

Comment: It means that when i'm filling the map it's reading from vector where the key is `MyObject.name` and value is the object itself. I used a pointer to avoid copying the object

Comment: Maybe look at [std::multimap::equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/).

Comment: Be very careful with that - make sure the vector never changes while you point at its contents - vectors can move things if you push_back

Comment: @doctorlove The function that returns the vector is `const`, do I also need to stress that in multimap declaration?

Comment: In addition to what Galik linked, you might want to use `std::multimap::count` to get the number of values with the key. Also, as long as no one modifies the `vector` during the lifetime of `dataMap` or it's possible copies, you'll be fine.

Comment: If you know the keys it's simple see equal_range, If not there are other questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554932/how-can-i-get-all-the-unique-keys-in-a-multimap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371236/is-there-an-iterator-across-unique-keys-in-a-stdmultimap

Comment: Strayed off topic - but what are you really trying to do? Count_if? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: @doctorlove kind of, but i need just one number that indicates how many same keys there are for a certain group

Answer (score 7):

From what I understand of your problem you can implement it using [std::multimap::equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/).

**Something a bit like this:**

```
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyObject
{
    std::string name;
    int information;

    MyObject(const std::string& name, int information)
    : name(name), information(information) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    std::vector<MyObject> dataVec;
    std::multimap<std::string, MyObject*> dataMap;

    // Give each object a random letter
    // between A-J as a name and some data
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        dataVec.emplace_back(std::string(1, 'A' + std::rand() % 10), i);

    // Fill dataMap from dataVec
    for(auto&& data: dataVec)
        dataMap.emplace(data.name, &data);

    // Select the correct type for calling the equal_range function
    decltype(dataMap.equal_range("")) range;

    // iterate through multimap's elements (by key)
    for(auto i = dataMap.begin(); i != dataMap.end(); i = range.second)
    {
        // Get the range of the current key
        range = dataMap.equal_range(i->first);

        // Now print out that whole range
        for(auto d = range.first; d != range.second; ++d)
            std::cout << d->first << ": " << d->second->information << '\n';
    }
}
```

**[Run It Here](https://ideone.com/df3Q1B)**

If that's not precisely what you want, maybe it will still give you ideas how to solve your specific problem.

Comment: That helped clear up some things, thanks :)

Comment: @user2202368 I didn't notice you had posted a solution in the question. The only real different I can see is that my version uses the returned `equal_range()` to select the next iterator in the outer for-loop which is probably slightly more efficient than calculating `upper_bound()` again.