# How to implement the below function getValue(m) for multimap in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void getValue(multimap<int,string> &m){
    for(auto &mValue : m){
        cout<<mValue.first<<" "<<mValue.second<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    multimap<int,string> m;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int num;
        string str;
        cin>>num;
        getline(cin,str);
        m.insert(make_pair(num,str));
    }
    

    getValue(m);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error :**
invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::map >&’ from expression of type ‘std::multimap >’
getValue(m);

Comment: Do not use `std::make_pair` with `emplace()` it does not make any sense.

Comment: If you're just trying to print unique keys in your multimap, does this answer your question? [is there an iterator across unique keys in a std::multimap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371236/is-there-an-iterator-across-unique-keys-in-a-stdmultimap)

Comment: You'll probably have this problem once it compiles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: A `std::multimap` is not a kind of `std::map`; they are unrelated types. `getValue` will have to accept a `std::multimap<int,string>` reference, or you could make it a function template.

Comment: `template <class M> void getValue(const M& m) { /*same code*/ }`

Comment: Side note: The time you save by only having to type `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is likely quickly eaten up by your builds taking ten times longer than using the required headers directly. Add to that the identifier minefield that results from including the entire C++ Standard Library and pulling it into the global namespace with `using namespace std` and you're writing some seriously brittle code that will require more compiles.

Comment: Rename `getValue` as `printValues`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I just wanted to say the same, and change references to `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map<int, std::string>` is a different type to `std::multimap<int, std::string>`, although they bear similarities.

The simplest way would to write a similar function:

```
void getValue(const std::multimap<int, std::string> &m){
    for(auto &mValue : m){
        std::cout<<mValue.first<<" "<<mValue.second<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

However there a a number of map-like containers in `std` and beyond, so you might want to change `getValue` to be a template

```
template <typename Map>
void getValue(const Map &m){
    for(auto &mValue : m){
        std::cout<<mValue.first<<" "<<mValue.second<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

You might want to constrain that to only accept map-like types, e.g. (with C++17's library addition of [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t))

```
template <typename Map>
std::void_t<typename Map::key_type, typename Map::mapped_type> getValue(const Map &m){
    for(auto &mValue : m){
        std::cout<<mValue.first<<" "<<mValue.second<<std::endl;
    }
}
```