# Stl multimap - how to get the list of values of all keys in the multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stl::multimap - how do i get groups of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data)

What i want to do is to compute the list of values of every key stored in the multimap.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you even done any basic research into how to use a `multimap`?

Comment: Have you understood my question? If you know the answer i would be pleased to hear...

Comment: Yes, I know the answer, but I'm not answering it because I think it's a lazy, poorly-researched question. It would be easy for you to find an answer yourself, if you made any effort. Google for "stl multimap" and you get how to iterate on a multimap as the **very first result** http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html

Comment: Wrong answer. You should read more carefully the question ( early, i have editated the title in order to express it more clearly). Consider that i do not know the keys...

Comment: That's why you should _iterate_. The example on the page I linked to shows how to print all the keys and values. Hmm, how could that possibly be helpful to get a list of all the keys and values?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`equal_range()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range); it returns a pair of iterators describing the range of items with the specified key.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how to iterate over all keys?

Comment: @MarcoMasci: Perhaps I misunderstand your original question.  It sounds like you want to know all the values corresponding to a particular key.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: No: i don't know the keys stored in it. I want to enumerate all keys stored in the multimap and, for every key, collect the associated values.

Answer (score 2):

A generic answer to the generic question is:

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE>
std::vector<VALUE> getValues(const std::multimap<KEY,VALUE>& aMap){
    std::vector<VALUE> values;
    for(multimap<KEY,VALUE>::const_iterator it=aMap.begin(), end=aMap.end();it!=end;++it){
        values.push_back((*it).second);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```
multimap<string, int> m;
vector<int> values;

for (multimap<string, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    values.push_back((*it).second);
}
```