# how to redundant item from a multimap

Tags: c++, set, multimap, redundancy

I have some file like following i need to remove the a multimap

```
 3KHJG 76  238
 3KHJG 86  238
 3GDMB 31  244
 3GDMB 31  247
 3GDMB 31  251
 3KOFA 21  336
 3KOFA 36  263
```

....

i need to get a file such as:

```
 3KHJG 81  238
 3GDMB 31  247
```

.....

// which keep the string key and calculate the avg of the next columns;

i have

```
 typedef struct S{
   int v1;
   int v2;
   ...
   }struct1;

struct1 s1;                 
//I parsed the old file and put them into a multimap and a set<string>;
multimap <string, s1> m;
multimap <string, s1>::iterator i;
set <string> pa_set;
int sumv1, sumv2;
int avgv1, avgv2;
for (set<string>:: iterator ip= pa_set.begin(); ip !=pa_set.end(); ip++)
{

  multimap <string, struct1> ::iterator i = m.find(*ip);

       int cnt=m.cout(*ip);
       if (ip != m.end())
      { 
        v1 =i->second.v1;
        v2 =i->second.v2;
        sumv1+=v1;
        sumv2+=v2;
        i++;
      }

      //calculate the avgv1 and avgv2;
}
```

however, if I used the if (){} it looks like i only iterator once?
 how can I go through all the interators fullfill

```
    multimap<string,struct1> ::iterator i = m. find(*ip) && i != m.end() ;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i mean i do know one way just use for ( i =0, i<m.count(*ip), ip++) is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/) function that will give you pair of iterators to the range from which you'll compute the averages.

Comment: is the m.equal_range(key) gives the lower and upper boundary?   if my m.count (key) actually is a number from 10-200?  how i go through all the items in between the lower and upper boundary ? is there a way to loop through every iterator one by one.  The only technique i know is erase each found key and cut down m.count (key) and use a while (m.count > 0 && condition2) loop, but I think there may be other methods...Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data.....Thanks! I think i did not fully realize how to implement the equal_range(key )until i see the above post...yes..you are right! the equal_range could be a choice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equal_range` for this, like:

```
equal_range(*ip);
```

Check [this example here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/).