# C++: Storing groups of three in a multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

I was wondering how you implement a multimap with groups of three values. For instance:
[{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}]

Do you have to use std::pair?

Comment: What sort of thing would be the lookup key?  Does your C++ support tuples?

Comment: Using the example I wrote above, a and d would be the lookup keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.   Using std::pair is a reasonable way to represent the values {b,c} and {e,f}
You would store each one in the multimap with key a, value {b,c} and key D, value {e,f}.

Then later you might have key a, value {z,y}.  When that is inserted, you can then find key a, and it will return a iterator that you can fetch all of the values associated with key a.

If you do have tuples, then you might consider using key a, with the tuple {a,b,c}.

Comment: There are many examples on this site and elsewhere.  Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data?rq=1   Look to the right on this page, under the Related stuff.   There are lots of good links that show you things about multimaps

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the key that represents itself a group of three values then for example you can use std::array as the key.

For example

```
std::multimap<std::array<int, 3>, std::string> m;
```