# Summing together same-key items from a multimap?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm aware this has been asked on here before:

[stl::multimap - how do i get groups of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data?rq=1)

but the answer:

```
pair<Iter, Iter> range = my_multimap.equal_range("Group1");
int total = accumulate(range.first, range.second, 0);
```

does not compile for me, when I do:

```
pair<multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator, multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator> range = multimap.equal_range(an_int);
float total = accumulate(range.first, range.second, 0);
```

This was on GCC 4.8

Could anyone confirm whether they can compile this/offer the correct answer?

Comment: and the error message is...?

Comment: 5k rep. Doesn't think it is appropriate to give compiler error message on compiler error question... Something is broken on stackoverflow.

Comment: @FélixCantournet or the compiler error is on on my work machine.... and I am not.

Comment: Error on GCC 4.9.2 is `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'int' and 'std::pair<const int, float>')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four problems with this code:

1. You have too many closing angle brackets.
2. Your multimap probably shouldn't be named `multimap`. (Although this *might* not cause a compile error, it's pretty obvious that you shouldn't do it.)
3. Dereferencing a multimap iterator gives a key-value *pair*, rather than just the value. So of course you can't sum these with `std::accumulate` directly.
4. Even if you did this with a multiset instead of a multimap, so #3 wouldn't apply, passing `0` as the initial value will cause all the floats to be truncated as it would deduce type `int` for the accumulator... so you would probably get the wrong answer.

It looks like you're stuck in 2003, since you actually wrote out the return type of `equal_range`, so I guess no lambdas or range-for-loops for you.

```
pair<multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator,
     multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator> range = M.equal_range(an_int);
float total = 0;
for (multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator I = range.first; I != range.second; ++I) {
    total += I->second;
}
```

Or avoid `equal_range` and that nasty declaration altogether...

```
float total = 0;
for (multimap<int32_t, float>::iterator I = M.lower_bound(an_int);
     I != M.end() && I->first == an_int;
     ++I) {
    total += I->second;
}
```

**Edit:** Okay, so you do have C++11 support. So you can do this:

```
auto range = M.equal_range(an_int);
float total = accumulate(range.first, range.second, 0.0,
                         [](float x, pair<int32_t, float> y) { return x + y.second; });
```

(Note: If you have C++14 support, you can even replace `pair<int32_t, float>` by `auto` in the lambda.)

Comment: Are you inferring Jerry's answer is not feasible?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, it appears he did overlook this fact (which someone else has now pointed out in a comment). It's a natural mistake to make.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in two lines? Perhaps a for_each, with accumulate?

Comment: @user997112 So do you have C++11 support or not?

Comment: yes, I just dont like using auto too much, as I sometimes like to see the type declaration.

Answer (score 3):

I believe gcc 4.8 already supported the C++11 redefinition of `auto`<sup>1</sup> and lambdas, so you should be able to use:

```
auto range = multimap.equal_range(an_int);
std::cout << std::accumulate(range.first, range.second, 0, 
    [](int a, std::pair<int32, float> b) { return a + b.second; });
```

[of course, you need to specify the name of *your* `multimap` object, where this has `multimap`.]

As an aside, since you're expecting the result as a `float`, you may want to change your initial value to a `float`, so the accumulation is done on `float`s, not `int`s:

```
std::cout << std::accumulate(range.first, range.second, 
    0.0f,
    [](float a, std::pair<int32, float> b) { return a + b.second; });
```

---

<sup>1. with the `-std=C++0x` flag.</sup>

Comment: @Snps: Oops--quite right. Corrected.